# Emberjs Scroll To Child Component

Tags: ember.js

In `Data Down, Actions Up` approach, what is the best way to scroll to a child component.

I have a collection of pages

```
{{#each pages as |page|}}
 {{single-page model=page}}
{{/each}}
```

and I want to scrollTo a specific page number.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a parent component that wraps what you have now, and looks something like this.

```
{{scrollable-pages pages=pages activePage=page)}}
```

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/d3c72de46566c03a7764988915b71d97?openFiles=components.scrollable-pages.js%2Ctemplates.components.single-page.hbs) that just scrolls down to the relevant page.

I'm not sure if you want to handle the scroll event ? In that case, the twiddle and relevant components will need to be expanded.

```
{{scrollable-pages pages=pages activePage=page onScroll=(action "changeActive")}}
```

So that you can handle that action and change the active page.

I would even consider another parent component in this case to manage the state, injecting a service with the pages, and handling the scroll change there.